# Unable to make Resteasy work with Tomcat 8 and Java 8

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, resteasy

I am trying to make a simple resteasy based API using JAVA 8 (v45) and tomcat 8(v23), however I don't see my calls resulting in any traffic or log activity.

My web.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

  <display-name>Test</display-name>

    <description>Test</description>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>resteasy</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>resteasy</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/restfulservices/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Auto scan REST service -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- this should be the same URL pattern as the servlet-mapping property -->

    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/restfulservices</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <resource-ref>
        <description>Oracle Datasource example</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/cboxDs</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>

    <!-- Environment entry examples -->
    <env-entry>
      <env-entry-name>test</env-entry-name>
      <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
      <env-entry-value>dev</env-entry-value>
    </env-entry>
  </web-app>
```

and my service class looks like this:

```
package test.request.service;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

@Path("/dihService")
public class testService {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(testService.class);

    @GET
    @Path("/hello")
    public Response getResponseMessage() {

        LOGGER.info(" Entered and param is :");
        return Response.status(200).entity(" Entered. Hello world").build();
    }
}
```

After I deploy, when i hit the following URL : http://localhost:10120/resteasy/restfulservices/dihService/hello

I expect some activity in the logs, however I am not seeing anything. I have already verified that my server is running on port 10120 and that my logs are otherwise flowing normally. Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

Your servlet config is mapped to URL that starts with /restfulservices as mentioned here:

```
  <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>resteasy</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/restfulservices/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

but your actual web service class does not use that URL part

```
@Path("/dihService")
public class testService {
```

so it will not be found. You need add `restfulservices` to your class mapping path as mentioned here:

```
@Path("/restfulservices /dihService")
public class testService {
```

Comment: Thanks Juned. I tried your suggestion and I still don't see anything in my logs and i continue to get a 404 error for the same URL.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I found out that in tomcat you always have an additional path (currently I don't know how to change that). Check the tomcat manager app http://localhost:8080/manager/html/list you'll find the path you need there for your deployed application. You should then be able to use

http://localhost:8080/somepath/restfulservices/dihService/

By the way I use the same structure of annotations like you did so the answer from Juned is not correct.

Regards
Steffen

Comment: Usually somepath is the name of your project/war.

Comment: It looks like the only possibility to change this behaviour is by renaming the war file to the desired path name. If you just want to have resteasy of first part of the path your war file would need to be renamed to resteasy.war.